# Trigger insert to another table if record inserted to table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have `tblA` and `tblB`.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                        tblA                        |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| id         | INT IDENTITY(1,1), PRIMARY KEY        |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
| usrnm      | nvarchar[50], NOT NULL                |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
| InsertDate | DateTime DEFAULT(getdate()), NOT NULL |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
```

and

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                        tblB                        |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| id         | INT IDENTITY(1,1), PRIMARY KEY        |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
| tblA_id    | INT, NOT NULL                         |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
| usrnm      | nvarchar[50], NOT NULL                |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
| InsertDate | DateTime DEFAULT(getdate()), NOT NULL |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Every time a record is being inserted to tblA I need to insert a record to tblB automatically.

```
INSERT INTO tblA (username, action) VALUES ('usrnm', '0')
```

So after the above code I need the below to run immediately:

```
INSERT INTO tblB (tblA_ID, username, action, InsertDate) 
VALUES
('id of the above record', 'usrnm', '0', 'InsertDate of the above rec')
```

Is this possible? I tried to figure out how to trigger it, but no luck.

**EDIT**:
OK, so based on the links I got it should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoInsert
ON tblA
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO tblB
    (tblA_id, usrnm, InsertDate)
    VALUES
    (inserted.id, inserted.usrnm, inserted.InsertDate)
```

Is that how I should reference to the tblA values?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Here is a good place to start:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inserted`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoInsert ON tblA AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblB (tblA_id, usrnm, InsertDate)
        select id, usrnm, InsertDate
        from inserted i;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `TRIGGER` on table A, something like this:

**SQL** *More about [After Triggers in SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)*

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
   ON tblA
   FOR INSERT
   AS
   BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      INSERT INTO tblB
        (id, name, etc)
    SELECT
        id, name, etc
        FROM inserted
    END
```

---

**MySQL** *More about [After Triggers in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)*

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
   AFTER INSERT ON tblA FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tblB (ID, name, etc)
      VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.name, NEW.etc)            
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```